# Jenkins/Groovy: How to pull specific part of a string

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a string that look like:

```
data = ABSIFHIEHFINE -2938 NODFNJN {[somedate]} oiejfoen
```

I need to pull `{[somedate]}` only with {[]} included.
I tried to do `data.substring(0, data.indexOf(']}'))` to remove the end of the string but it is also removing the symbols that I need to keep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to pull {[somedate]} only with {[]} included.

```
def data = 'ABSIFHIEHFINE -2938 NODFNJN {[somedate]} oiejfoen'

// you could do error checking on these to ensure
// >= 0 and end > start and handle that however 
// is appropriate for your requirements...
def start = data.indexOf '{['
def end = data.indexOf ']}'

def result = data[start..(end+1)]

assert result ==  '{[somedate]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using regular expression search:

```java
data = "ABSIFHIEHFINE -2938 NODFNJN {[somedate]} oiejfoen"
def matcher = data =~ /\{\[.+?\]\}/
if( matcher ) {
    echo matcher[0]
}
else {
    echo "no match"
}
```

Output:

```text
{[somedate]}
```

**Explanations:**

- `=~` is the find operator. It creates a `java.util.regex.Matcher`.
- The string between the forward slashes (which is just another way to define a string literal), is the regular expression: `\{\[.+?\]\}`
- **RegEx** breakdown:

  - `\{\[` - literal `{` and `[` which must be escaped because they have special meaning in RegEx
  - `.+?` - any character, at least one, as little as possible (to support finding multiple sub strings enclosed in `{[]}`)
  - `\]\}` - literal `]` and `}` which must be escaped because they have special meaning in RegEx
- You can [test the RegEx only](https://regex101.com/r/aJDEfY/1) or use [Groovy IDE](https://groovyide.com/playground) to test the full sample code (replace `echo` by `println`).